# How to create unique id in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I have the following collection example:

```
{
  _id: 'asdfjklsfo',
  name: 'My name',
  sections: [
    {
      title: 'my title'
    },
    {
      title: 'second title'
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want all the `sections` to have a unique id so that I can easily add/remove sections.

How can I create a unique id for each section?

This is the current method I have to add a new section:

```
collection.findAndModify({id: id}, {$push:{sections:{title: 'New title'}}}, {new: true})
```

I'm using [Monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk) as my DBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer in the Monk documentation under [Casting](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk#casting).

> users.id() // returns new generated ObjectID

In this case users is a collection from `var users= db.get('users')` so just calling `.id()` generates a unique id.

So in my case, I just had to do

```
collection.findAndModify({_id: id}, {$push:{sections:{section_id: collection.id(), name: name, description: description}}})
```